# 360works how to attach file inline to embed image

Tags: html, filemaker

I have 360works for filemaker and want to place a image inside a html email. How is this image embedded?

For example:

```
<img src=\"cid:footergif456\ ">"
```

Comment: where abouts would it source the image from within filemaker

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://static.360works.com/plugins/EMAILPLUG/documentation.html#EmailAttachFileInline):

You set your message body to some HTML which has an image tag like you have.

Then you need to call `EmailAttachFileInline`, eg

`EmailAttachFileInline( Globals::headerContainer ; "footergif456" )`

The plugin will send a multi-part email, and email clients are supposed to get the image from the appropriate part.